# Android throws exception when sending UDP packet

Tags: android, udp, send, ping

I'm trying to send a UDP packet to a server to see if it is online. I have made a stand alone app to do exactly that and it works without a problem but when putting the code in the app and calling the function it throws an exception when it goes to actually send the packet. I have done a lot of research and I can't find any reason why. I replaced the IP with a fake one because I don't want to post the actual IP. Thanks for the help in advanced.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

import android.app.Activity;

public class CheckStatus extends Activity {
//Check if the server is online

public static boolean check() {

    try {
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("11.11.11.11");
        //create socket
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        //set timeout
        clientSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
        //send packet

        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(Integer.toBinaryString(0x0006000000).getBytes(), 5, address, 44462);

        clientSocket.send(p);//throws exception here

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        clientSocket.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

When printing the exception i got "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: You're catching Exception but not printing out the stack trace... how are you supposed to know what went wrong?

Comment: Yup sorry should have done that.. I ran it again and got this "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: Simple: Android doesn't do networking on its main (UI) thread since 3.0+. Consider using a seperate thread. Not so simple: you want to return a value from a static method. Getting results from threads isn't the simplest task. **If** you were publishing results to a UI, this would be easier (via AsyncTask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare this `asyncTask` in the `activity` and call your `check()` method from there.

**EDIT:**

```
private class CheckStatusTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Boolean> {        
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        boolean flag = check();
        return flag;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean flag) {
       // use your flag here to check true/false.
    }       
}
```

And make this call :

```
new CheckStatusTask().execute();
```

Reference :

[Painless threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Comment: I think its executing it however im not quite sure how to get this to tell me if the server responded or not. Sorry im new to android and UDP.

Comment: @user1998603 see my edit. by that you will are able to get result after your `check()` method execution completion.

Comment: So i got it to work at first but once a new page is loaded it says its offline. What i did was created a private variable called "online" in the CheckStatusTask and then in the onPostExecute i set online = to flag and created another function called getOnline() which returned the boolean online. So when ever i needed the boolean i just called CheckStatusTask.getOnline() which works on the first page load but once i load a new page it changes to offline